# Upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 all I get when I boot up is MEMTEST86 I have tried to access grub and theer is only memtest in there

Tags: grub2, system-installation, memory-test

12.04 upgrade to 12.10 all I get when I boot up is MEMTEST86 I have tried to access grub and there is only memtest in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: There's a section in this question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) regarding issue with grub.

Comment: I don't see how the above mentioned Q&A addresses this. This Q is about a Grub configuration with only a Memtest entry.

Answer (score 1):

**Super Grub2 Disk** - creates a bootable CD [from here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)

Boot from the CD, choose the partition with Ubuntu.
From Ubuntu Terminal gives the command:

> sudo update-grub

Restart.